# Two dataframes in one grouped barplot

Tags: r

I have this two dataframes. I'm having trouble trying to put this two variables in one grouped barplot

```
> dxmale
F20 F25 F31 F32 F33 F34 F41 
  1   3   1   5   9   3   3 

> dxfemale
F06 F20 F25 F28 F31 F32 F33 F34 F40 F41 F42 F50 F60 
  2   1   3   1   7   7  28   4   1  20   1   2   2
```

One of the main problems is that many of these columns don't match. I would like to put in a grouped barplot so, if there is no value from one column, in the barplot would be shown as "0".

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are these data.frames or named vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `melt` (or `stack` from `base R` - as @rawr mentioned)  the `vector`s and `merge` it

```
 library(reshape2)
 dM <- merge(melt(dxmale), melt(dxfemale), by="row.names", all=TRUE)
```

If needed, the NA can be replaced by 0.

```
 dM[is.na(dM)] <- 0
 colnames(dM)[2:3] <- c("male", "female")
```

and then do the `barplot`

```
 barplot(`colnames<-`(t(dM[-1]), dM[,1]), beside=TRUE, legend=TRUE)
```

[image]

#### Update

If we need to order by the `sum` of 'male' and 'female' columns

```
dM1 <- dM[order(Reduce(`+`, dM[-1])),]
barplot(`colnames<-`(t(dM1[-1]), dM1[,1]), beside=TRUE, legend=TRUE)
```

#### data

```
dxmale <- structure(c(1, 3, 1, 5, 9, 3, 3), .Names = 
c("F20", "F25", "F31", "F32", "F33", "F34", "F41"))

dxfemale <- structure(c(2, 1, 3, 1, 7, 7, 28, 4, 1, 20, 1, 
 2, 2), .Names = c("F06", 
"F20", "F25", "F28", "F31", "F32", "F33", "F34", "F40", "F41", 
"F42", "F50", "F60"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a great barplot. 
Is there any way to sort the bars by decreasing order?

Comment: @CarlosMedina As we have two columns ie. dxmale and dxfemale, I am not sure which column you want as base for ordering.

Comment: It would be great if the barplot was ordered by the sum of both values of each column (dxmale+dxfemale)

Comment: @CarlosMedina  Updated the post based on your suggestion

Comment: Thank you very very very much for your help!!!!. You have avoided one person to have a stroke because of R :D

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution based on `base` R and lattice `barchart` for the barplot.

First we merge the data frames using `stack` ( to put data in the long format) and `merge`:

```
 mm <- merge(stack(dxfemale),stack(dxmale),
            by="ind",all=TRUE,
  suffixes=c("male","female"))
```

Then the call to `barchart` is straight forward in the wide format:

```
 barchart(valuesmale+valuesfemale~ind,mm,auto.key=TRUE)
```

[image]